# Spring MVC Controller redirect to different controller and keep information

Tags: spring, redirect, model-view-controller, controller

What I want to achieve:

When a User clicks an interest button on a property that they are interested in, they will be redirected to the same page. Only this time, there will be a tag which states "you have expressed an interest in this property" which will be displayed visible to the User. I have managed to redirect to the second page but the words "you have expressed an interest in this property" don't appear.

What I have so far:

When a user clicks an "interest" button on a property JSP page they are directed to the Controller, below. This Controller handles the request and gets the Property that they that clicked from the Database. I then set "setExpressInterest" boolean to true for that property.

```
  @RequestMapping(value="/expressInterest/{propertyId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String expressInterest(@PathVariable int propertyId, SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper request){

  Property property = propertyRepo.findById(propertyId);
  property.setExpressInterest(true);
  return "redirect:/property/{propertyId}";

}
```

I redirect the request to the next controller below:

The Controller below, get the property id from the first Controller. I set it equal to a property instance.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/property/{propertyId}")
public ModelAndView viewProperty(@PathVariable int propertyId, SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper request) {

   ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("property");

   Property property = propertyRepo.findById(propertyId);



      if (property.isExpressInterest() == true){
        mav.addObject("isExpress", true);
      }


    mav.addObject("property", property);
    return mav;  
 }
```

```html
 <div>
          <c:if test="${property.expressInterest}">
             <strong>You have expressed interest in property</strong>
          </c:if>
          </div>
```

I would appreciate any assistance on how to address this problem. Or any links to useful articles.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add the line propertyRepo.save(property). This meant that the data was not saved into the repo.

> ```
>    @RequestMapping(value="/expressInterest/{propertyId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
>   public String expressInterest(@PathVariable int propertyId,   SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper request){
>   Property property = propertyRepo.findById(propertyId);
>   property.setExpressInterest(true);
>   propertyRepo.save(property);
>   return "redirect:/property/{propertyId}";
> ```

}